# Did Charlies Peirce write this sentence or something closely related in meaning?

Tags: metaphysics, history-of-philosophy, consciousness

I saw the following phrase recently and I was surprised that it was ascribed to Peire:
"We do not really think, we are barely conscious, until something goes wrong"
Did Charlies Peirce write this sentence or something closely related in meaning?

Comment: I did not find it in Collected Papers, but that does not mean it is not genuine, Peirce's oeuvre is very scattered. He certainly wrote things in this general vain, e.g. in [Fixation of Belief](http://www.peirce.org/writings/p107.html):"*We seem to be so constituted that in the absence of any facts to go upon we are happy and self-satisfied... The irritation of doubt is the only immediate motive for the struggle to attain belief.*"

Comment: Similar to Kant's "dogmatic slumber" that lasted until he ran into Hume and... it didn't go right, I suppose

Comment: We are supposed to be rational, only holding the rational (explainable) beliefs... few people can honestly claim that they do.